# retrive data (count , etc(user data ) ) from pivot table laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the below tables and I want to retrieve the number of each comment likes with users that liked the comment (something like Instagram comment which any body can like another user comments)

| users table |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

| Asks table |
| --- |
| id |
| title |

| comments table |
| --- |
| id |
| ask_id |
| user_id |
| text |

| comment_like table |
| --- |
| id |
| comment_id |
| user_id |

it used for saving comment links, it looks like Instagram comment which any user can like another user comment.

here is my User Model Code:

```
 class User extends Authenticatable
    {

public function comments_like()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Comment::class,
        'comment_like' ,
        'user_id' ,
        'comment_id' ,
        'id',
        'id'
    );
}



public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);

}

}
```

here is my Ask Model Code:

```
class Ask extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
protected $table = 'asks';

protected $fillable = ['title'];


public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}


}
```

here is my User Model Code:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

public function comments_like()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Comment::class,
        'comment_like' ,
        'user_id' ,
        'comment_id' ,
        'id',
        'id'
    );
}



public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);

}

}
```

here is my Comment Model Code:

```
    class Comment extends Model
    {

    
    //user relation
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }


    //ask relation
    public function ask()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ask::class);
    }

    //comment_like relation
    public function users_like ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            User::class ,
            'comment_like',
            'comment_id',
            'user_id',
            'id',
            'id'
        )
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

//condition on comment_like relation
    public function user_like_byId($id)
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany(
            User::class ,
            'comment_like',
            'comment_id',
            'user_id',
            'id',
            'id'

        )
            ->where('id',$id)->get();
    }


}
```

I want to retrieve latest ask with their comments which include count and data of comment_like**

I used this code but it show error

```
    $ask= Ask::query()->latest('id')->get()->first();
    foreach ($ask->comments()->get() as $commentItem) {
    
                echo "id: ".$commentItem->id .'<br>';
                echo "name :" .$commentItem->user()->pluck('name')[0] . "<br>";
                echo "text :" .$commentItem->text . "<br>";
    
               echo $commentItem->user_like_byId($commentItem->id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a resource with `php artisan make:resource AskResource` for your fetched data and use `count()` function for get length of data.

Comment: its not about api / my question was about realtions